# "Cannot read property 'contentType' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, ejs, multer

I've been working on a little image sharing social media app for the past week. Everything was going great until I had to implement retrieving images from the database.

I keep getting a "Cannot read property 'contentType' of undefined" error when,

1. There *is* data assigned to "contentType" and,
2. since at this moment, there is no images in the database, it shouldn't even look for the contentType. (see code for an example)

If somebody could help guide to the right direction, that would be really great!

FYI: There is are ***no*** images in the database what-so-ever. The upload works perfectly fine, it's just the retrieving that causes the issues - Yes I know, you can't retrieve images that *aren't there* but it shouldn't even look for the contentType in the first place.

Here's the code:

**Index route (This is the route where the error occurs)**

```
// @ROUTE: Home Route
// @DESCRIPTION: Renders the homepage
server.get('/', (req, res)=> {
    filesDB.find({}, (err, data)=> {
        if(err) {
            throw err
        }

        if(!data) {
            console.log("No Images")
        } else if(data) {
            res.render('Home.ejs', {
                pageTitle: "Home :: ImgHub",
                curSession: req.session,
                images: [data]
            })
        }
    })
})
```

**Home.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title><%= pageTitle %></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <%- include('./Partials/Header.ejs') %> 
        </header>
        <main>
            <% if(images.length > 0) { %>
                <% images.forEach((images)=> { %>
                    <div>
                        <img src="data:images/<%= images.img.contentType %>;base64, <%= images.img.data.toString('base64') %>">
                    </div>
                <% }) %>
            <% } else { %>
                <h2>No Images Found...</h2>
            <% } %>
        </main>
    </body> 
</html>
```

**Upload Post**

```
// @POST: Upload Post
// @DESCRIPTION: Saves the image's data onto the database.
server.post('/api/upload', fileUpload.single('fileInput'), (req, res)=> {
    const newFile = new filesDB({
        img: {
            data: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname + '/Uploads/' + req.file.filename)),
            contentType: 'image/png'
        },
        uploader: req.session.username
    })

    newFile.save((err, data)=> {
        if(err) {
            throw err
        } else {
            console.log(`> ${req.session.username} has uploaded: ${req.file.filename}`)
            res.redirect('/')
        }
    })
})
```

**Upload File Schema & Model**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const fileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    img: {
        data: Buffer,
        contentType: String
    },
    uploader: String
}, {timestamps: true})

const fileModel = new mongoose.model('file', fileSchema)
module.exports = fileModel
```

**Error**

```
TypeError: D:\Github Repositories\Repositories\ImgHub\ImgHub\views\Home.ejs:17
    15|                 <% images.forEach((images)=> { %>

    16|                     <div>

 >> 17|                         <img src="data:images/<%= images.img.contentType %>;base64, <%= images.img.data.toString('base64') %>">

    18|                     </div>

    19|                 <% }) %>

    20|             <% } else { %>


Cannot read property 'contentType' of undefined
    at eval (eval at compile (D:\Github Repositories\Repositories\ImgHub\ImgHub\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:662:12), <anonymous>:24:37)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at eval (eval at compile (D:\Github Repositories\Repositories\ImgHub\ImgHub\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:662:12), <anonymous>:21:15)
    at Home (D:\Github Repositories\Repositories\ImgHub\ImgHub\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:692:17)
    at tryHandleCache (D:\Github Repositories\Repositories\ImgHub\ImgHub\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:272:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (D:\Github Repositories\Repositories\ImgHub\ImgHub\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:489:10)
    at View.render (D:\Github Repositories\Repositories\ImgHub\ImgHub\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (D:\Github Repositories\Repositories\ImgHub\ImgHub\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (D:\Github Repositories\Repositories\ImgHub\ImgHub\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (D:\Github Repositories\Repositories\ImgHub\ImgHub\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
    at D:\Github Repositories\Repositories\ImgHub\ImgHub\server.js:94:17
    at D:\Github Repositories\Repositories\ImgHub\ImgHub\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:5068:18
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
```

**Image Model**
https://i.imgur.com/efHHRc9_d.webp?maxwidth=760&fidelity=grand

Comment: According to that error, your `data` returned from `filesDB.find` doesn't contain an `.img` field. Also is `data` one object, or an array of objects? That'd explain the issue.

Comment: @Kelvin Schoofs it's an array of objects. Let me upload an image and show you how the model looks like!

Comment: If it's an array of objects, and you're using `images: [data]`, then that's what's wrong.

Comment: I did the same thing with an old project of mine (I'm more than happy to send the link for github), and it worked fine. Do you have any idea what I should do?

Comment: I've posted an answer with the link to the documentation. Your `data` is indeed an **array of objects**, not just a single object. That's why your `.img` is undefined, as you're basically doing `[obj1, obj2, ...].img`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Mongoose API](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find), your `filesDB.find` returns an **array** of objects, not just a single object. Therefore your `images: [data]` is incorrect, and instead you need to use:

```js
        if(!data.length) {
            console.log("No Images")
        } else {
            res.render('Home.ejs', {
                pageTitle: "Home :: ImgHub",
                curSession: req.session,
                images: data,
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

When calling `find` on a mongo collection, it will return an empty array if no data can be found. Then, your check :

```
if(!data) {
    console.log("No Images")
} else if(data) {
    res.render('Home.ejs', {
        pageTitle: "Home :: ImgHub",
        curSession: req.session,
        images: [data]
    })
}
```

Will go in the else case, as `[]` is truthy. And when calling render, the images attribute will be `[[]]`, so have a length of 1 and pass the `images.length > 0` check.

Change your code to the following and you should see what you want

```
if(data.length === 0) {
    console.log("No Images")
} else {
    res.render('Home.ejs', {
        pageTitle: "Home :: ImgHub",
        curSession: req.session,
        images: data
    })
}
```